# Не могу поменять ничего в админ панели Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

Не могу ничего поменять в админ панели django, я думаю что проблема в postgresql, но может быть в что нибудь другом, вот код ошибки если понадобится:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/goods/products/12/change/
```

������������:  INSERT ������ UPDATE �� �������������� "django_admin_log" ���������������� ���������������������� ���������������� ���������� "django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  �������� (user_id)=(4) ���������������������� �� �������������� "auth_user".

Comment: Попробуйте победить кодировку, и прислать полный текст ошибки. И будет наглядно, если вы предоставите код. А так же убедитесь, что вы выполнили команду "python manage.py migrate"

Comment: а как победить кодировку?